# PHP and classes - write in session overwrites local variable

Tags: php, class, session, variables, include

I have an ***index.php*** with the following content:

```
include_once('includes/auth.php');
include_once('classes/class.DatabaseQuery.php');
include_once('classes/class.Project.php');
include_once('classes/class.User.php');

$project = new Project();
$user = new User();

// HTML, HEAD, BODY

$usergroup = $user->getUserGroup($_SESSION['user']);
// ...
```

So I include all needed classes in my index.php. I also create an instance of the classes in this file. Then I have my class files (e.g. ***class.Project***):

```
class Project {

private $db;
private $evaluation;

public function __construct($id=null){
    $this->setPreferences();
}

private function setPreferences() {
    $this->db = new DatabaseQuery();
    $this->evaluation = new Evaluation();
}


public function getSomething(){
    if($this->evaluation->checkSomething(1)){
        echo "test";
    }
}
 // ...
}
```

In these files I declare my other classes as private variables. Than I access the methods of the other classes.

Are there any problems with the inclusion and the use of private variables with other classes?

Now I have a strange problem. If I write a value into `$_SESSION['user']` my private variable `user` is overwritten. The session values are already filled before I write something in my session. Here is my ***login.php***:

```
    include_once('classes/class.User.php');     
    session_start();

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $user = new User();
    if ($user->checkLoginData($username, $password)) {
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $user->getUserIDForName($username);
        // it is an object
        var_dump($user);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        // it is a string
        var_dump($user);
        // ...
    }
```

How can `$_SESSION['user']=$username` change the content of the local variable `$user`? Perhaps you have some ideas what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "Are there any problems with the inclusion and the use of private variables with other classes?" Nopez. However I do have a problem with the tight coupling. It would be better to inject the instances as parameters of the method. This is called [Dependency Injection](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: @PeeHaa: I changed that by setting the database and so on with a function. There are no more new statements in the class. I observed recursion one time where the object was in the session and I printed out the session. Because each objects links on each other a recursion occurs. Should that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Now I followed the advice from [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/12953.htm), where `register_globals` should be turned of. E.g. with `htaccess`:

`php_value register_globals 0`

Seems to work.